# How to detect when there is no value from database SQL LINQ C#

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, linq

I'm having trouble with detecting when my value in C# code is null or not, (***I'm using LINQ to call stored procedures from SQL SERVER***), I mean I have issues when I want to determine did SQL returned something to me after I called SP which expecting one parameter (ArticleID) or acctualy SQL did not return anything ( null  -  row does not exist ).

In fact, I want to check does any of my articles has some "Sub articles", and I'm passing ArticleID from C# code to stored procedure.

So In case if article is there, I want to do something with it, in case article with passed ArticleID does not exist I want to do something also, so as I said I need to detect does my article with given ArticleID exist in my sql database.

Here is some of my code:

```
private void btnCheckForArticle(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        try
        {  
        if (gridArticles.SelectedItems.Count > 0) {
            Article a = (Article)gridArticles.SelectedItem;



                if (a.ArticleID != null)
                {

                    var existingArticle = DataServices.POS.proc_GetSubArticleByArticleID(a.ArticleID);
                    if (existingArticle != null)
                    {
                       //DO SOMETHING
                        return;
                    }
              }
        }
    }
}
```

My stored procedure :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_GetSubArticleByArticleID]
(
    @ArticleID int
)
AS
BEGIN
Select *
From SubArticles as S
Where S.ArticleID = @ArticleID
END
```

It's interesting that I do not know how to detect in c# code is my value null or not, because obliviosuly even if there is no row in sql database still I'm not getting null, and because of that code below `existingArticle != null` will allways execute..

Now I will post what is happening with article which for sure does not have any subarticles, I mean, where result **should be null 100%**!

[image]

ID that I passed to procedure is 2351, so I executed sp which should return value directly on sql and I replaced @ArticleID with 2351 and ofcourse It did not return me any results, but how can I notice that in my C# code..

because `existingArticle` will never be null cuz somehow it allways has some value and code below my  `if (existingArticle != null)` will allways execute. what I really dont want :/ ...

Thanks guys!
Cheers

Comment: what is the return type of `proc_GetSubArticleByArticleID` method? if it is `IEnumerable<Article>`, call `FirstOrDefault()` and compare with null

Comment: If using Linq, can't you use `if (existingArticle.Any())`?

Comment: @Roxy'Pro Did it solved your Problem

Comment: @Cataklysim I will check for it in a few hours, Im driving for few hrs allready so I can't code now. But to all thanks a lot! This is great community!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you call FirstOrDefault()

```
var existingArticle = DataServices.POS.proc_GetSubArticleByArticleID(a.ArticleID).FirstOrDefault();

if (existingArticle != null)
{
    // 
    return;
}
```

Comment: If you get called out as answer, may you put my answer also to yours as edit? Cause your way "transforms" it into a casual Null value and my answer shows how to filter a database Null value. Both should be interesting for people with the same question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a special Datatype for checking null values from a database.

`DBNull.Value`

In your case:

```
if (existingArticle != DBNull.Value)
{
   //DO SOMETHING
   return;
}
```

Comment: What if the column is a *non-nullable* column?

Comment: @Rahul if so, it will pass this statement. But for those you must ask different. In his question it was just asked how to see if a column is null or not. And a simple `if(columnA != null)` won't work, because the `Database NULL` Value is different then the `.Net NULL`

Comment: @Cataklysim .FirstOrDefault() fixed it

Answer (score 0):

First, modify your SP to have after `BEGIN`:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
```

This is to avoid interference of "xx rows affected" message.

Seccond, dont do `SELECT *`, instead use

```
SELECT 1 From SubArticles as S
Where S.ArticleID = @ArticleID
```

Last, check for `System.DBNull.Value` instead of NULL, as this is what will be returned from DDBB. This is because in .Net value types as Boolean can't be null